# Test Outlook VSTO add-in

Tags: c#, testing, outlook, vsto

I wrote an Outlook add-in roughly a year ago. The add-in reacts to new e-mails in specific folders.

Now to get rid of some bugs, I need to let my add-in run out of Visual Studio. Problem is, I can't let it run against the installed Outlook since I don't get 'enough' emails.

Is there a solution for that? Something like a fake-Outlook I could install? Or just something that will generate a bunch of e-mails inside an Outlook account?

Both things would be equally 'okay' for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, just found a probable solution: Apache JMeter.

After starting it one can right-click on 'Workbench', select 'Add' -> 'Sampler' -> 'SMTP Sampler'.

Or, you can add a Thread-Group inside the Testplan and add the same sampler there.

In the sampler you can enter log-in informations, the target and source address, the subject and a messagebody. When you are done configuring everything, just click play.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script or Program, which will send these emails automatically.

You can read, how you can send an email [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a75533eb-131b-4ff3-a3b2-b6df87c25cc8/how-do-i-send-mail-using-c?forum=netfxnetcom), but basicly you culd use something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Amount; i++)
{
  smtp.Send(message);
  Thread.sleep(timeToWait);
}
```

Or you could just simply send yourself emails.

Comment: the problem is that I need at least one e-mail/second and I need to be able to identify an email by it's header (that's just for me, not for the add-in). I could write it myself, yes. But I think that somewhere 'out there' has already done exactly that.

Comment: Ahh, okey. I don't know any tools, but im sure there is something like this out there. Sorry for this useless answer...